# Counting timestamp considering time and date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

How do I count timestamp considering both date and time range?For example, I want to count how many cells are within 2/14/2018 22:00 to 2/15/2018 1:00.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en).

Let say that you have

- J1 : 2/14/2018 22:00
- J2 : 2/15/2018 1:00

Then the formula to use could be

```
=COUNTIFS(G2:G,">="&J1,"=<"&J2)
```